# How to fill in missing columns in Stargazer in R?

Tags: r, lm, summary, stargazer, coefficients

I am working with the `lm` command and the `coeftest` command. I want to put them together into a `stargazer` table. The problem is that the `stargazer` output is incomplete.

Here is what I have so far. The left side is the OLS model. On the right side is the OLS model passed through the `coeftest` command.

```
=================================================
                         Dependent Variable:     
                    -----------------------------
                     VAP Turnout (%)             
                           (1)            (2)    
-------------------------------------------------
X                         -0.010         -0.010  
                         (0.031)        (0.035)  
                                                 
Constant                495.158***     495.158***
                         (17.493)       (20.561) 
                                                 
-------------------------------------------------
Observations              1,000                  
Adjusted R2               -0.001                 
Residual Std. Error 287.218 (df = 998)           
=================================================
Note:                 *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

1. How can I move `VAP Turnout (%)` back to the center in the stargazer table?
2. How can I manually enter `Observations`, `Adjusted R2`, and `Residual Std. Error` into the blank area under model 2 (the OLS object passed through the `coeftest` command).

Thank you for your help!

Here is the code to reproduce the table:

```
#Packages
library(stargazer)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

#Set Seed
set.seed(1993)

#Create Sample Data
X <- sample(seq(1, 1000), 1000, replace = T)
Y <- sample(seq(1, 1000), 1000, replace = T)
Cluster <- sample(letters, 1000, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(X, Y, Cluster)

#Model 1 - OLS
Base <- lm(Y ~ X, data = df)

#Model 2 - Coeftest
Coeff_Test <- coeftest(Base, vcovCL, cluster = df$Cluster)

#Stargazer table
stargazer(list(Base, Coeff_Test), type = "text",omit=c("Cluster"),
          model.names = FALSE,
          dep.var.caption = c("Dependent Variable:"),
          dep.var.labels   = c("VAP Turnout (%)"), #Write the DV Here
          omit.stat = c("f","rsq"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the standard errors and p-values from the `coeftest` using the `tidy` function in the `broom` package. From there, you can manually input both the standard errors and the p-values into the stargazer function using the `se` and `p` arguments.

Note that when you use the `NULL` in the `se` and `p` arguments, it manually defaults to whatever object is listed in the corresponding position. In this case, we use it in the first position to default to the base object but input the standard errors and p-values manually into the second position.

Lastly, since you are simply clustering the standard errors, the coefficients and model specification values stay the same. So, we can
can put the corresponding model, the object `base`, into the second argument, so it feeds in the coefficients and model specification values while we override the se and p-values ourselves.

```
#Packages
library(stargazer)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

#Set Seed
set.seed(1993)

#Create Sample Data
X <- sample(seq(1, 1000), 1000, replace = T)
Y <- sample(seq(1, 1000), 1000, replace = T)
Cluster <- sample(letters, 1000, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(X, Y, Cluster)

#Model 1 - OLS
Base <- lm(Y ~ X, data = df)

#Model 2 - Coeftest
Coeff_Test <- coeftest(Base, vcovCL, cluster = df$Cluster)

#Make into a DF and extract the SE and P-Values
library(broom)
Coeff_Test_DF <- tidy(Coeff_Test)
#Coeff_Test_DF$std.error
#Coeff_Test_DF$p.value

#Stargazer table
stargazer(list(Base, Base), type = "text",omit=c("Cluster"),
          model.names = FALSE,
          se = list(NULL, Coeff_Test_DF$std.error),
          p = list(NULL, Coeff_Test_DF$p.value),
          dep.var.caption = c("Dependent Variable:"),
          dep.var.labels   = c("VAP Turnout (%)"), #Write the DV Here
          omit.stat = c("f","rsq"))
```

```
t test of coefficients:

               Estimate  Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 495.1580645  20.5610666 24.0823 <0.0000000000000002 ***
X            -0.0098368   0.0346685 -0.2837              0.7767    
---
```

```
===========================================================
                                   Dependent Variable:     
                               ----------------------------
                                     VAP Turnout (%)       
                                    (1)            (2)     
-----------------------------------------------------------
X                                  -0.010        -0.010    
                                  (0.031)        (0.035)   
                                                           
Constant                         495.158***    495.158***  
                                  (17.493)      (20.561)   
                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                       1,000          1,000    
Adjusted R2                        -0.001        -0.001    
Residual Std. Error (df = 998)    287.218        287.218   
===========================================================
Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: So did you get your `VAP Turnout (%)` back to the center?

Comment: I did! This code successfully puts `VAP Turnout (%)` back into the center of the coefficients in the table